# Chrome packaged app, user sing in

Tags: google-chrome-app

i'm writing a chrome packaged app, i'm using chrome.identity to get user email id from chrome browser. But, now if user is not logged in chrome browser i want to redirect him to  [chrome://chrome-signin/?source=0](http://chrome://chrome-signin/?source=0). To achieve this i tried using windows.open(),but page always open blank, so later i tired it with **chrome.browser.openTab** api with **"browser"** permission in manifest json, but it is throwing error.
What is the proper way to do it ,what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing **(as of 2015-03-22)** the following notice on the [API documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/browser):

> This API is in beta. It is only available to Chrome users on the beta channel and dev channel.

According to [bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=358315), it is expected to get to stable soon, but possibly not in Chrome 42. The current Stable release is 41.

Comment: so how to do it? Hangout application do the same thing,  still trying to solve this jigsaw.

Comment: `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` with `interactive` set?

Comment: i just need to open chrome://chrome-signin/?source=0 link, which is under chrome setting, no need of  authentication.  I saw this in Google hangout app, when i'm not signed  in my chrome browser, app ask me to sign in , i want to do the same.

Comment: Do note that Hangouts app can cheat, since it can use whitelist-only APIs.

Comment: it means we have no way :( , i'm trying to understand code in hangout js file.